# Error in Math.random() for arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I'm sure this is a small, stupid error that I just can't see.
I'm getting a compiling error in this code:

```
private String setQuestions(){
int match = Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.length); }
```

in my length.

Compiling error is:

"Cannot find symbol
symbol: variable length
location: variable cities of type ArrrayList  "

How can I fix this?  I do want to use Math.random();

Also not sure if this makes a difference, but this is is being done within a String method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lists don't have a field `length` like arrays. they have a method `size()` that returns the current size. Edit: Also please note that this error has absolutly nothing to do with Math.random(). You should rather use the error message you get as a title for your stackoverflow questions than guess and have titles that actually don't really have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS good point, will keep that in mind next time :-)

Comment: there is more than that. you method is missing a return statement, too.

Comment: I do have a return statement, I just hadn't added it to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `cities` is of type `ArrayList` you have to use `cities.size()` instead of `cities.length`.

Comment: I've tried that:   int match = Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.size()); but it still doesn't work??  cities is an ArrayList

Comment: Change it to this version: `int match = (int) (Math.random() * new cities.size());`

Comment: Never mind got it:  int match = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.size());  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors here.

First: If your method is not `void` is because you're gonna return something, in your method you should `return` a `String`.

Second: The result of `Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.length)` it's a double, so you can't store on a simple `int`, you should parse it or just change the `int` for `double`

Third: If you wanna `return` that `match` variable you should parse it to a `String` like you're declaring or just change the declaration to `double`.

---

So, the easier fix would be just changing the `string` and `int` for `double` and return it like this:

```
    private static double setQuestions(){

        double match = Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.length);

        return match;
    }
```

---

Remember if you want to use the `double` returned you should store it when you call it, like this:

```
double result = setQuestions();
```

---

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The code has three problems:

**First**, the variable "cities" is an ArrayList, as the compiller error wrote. ArrayList is a Collection which implements the interface List. The size of any implementations of List is accessable by method size(). Than, you should change cities.length by cities.size() or you turn cities as array.

**Second**, you defined the variable "match" as an int value but method floor from Math return a double. If you really want "match" to be a int, than you can use the cast against the method floor, that is, you code become: int match = (int) Math.random()*cities.size();

**Third**, your method requires an String as return, than you should return the String object correctly.